# Is there any event that rise when TextView is invalidated?

Tags: android, events, textview, invalidation

I want to run a method when my TextView is invalidated. Is there any event for this?

If not is there any other way to catch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not. I found nothing about this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onFocusChange listener, And in that you can see if required view get focused or not, and can check the value of it.

[see what docs says.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)